# CMake - как переместить файлы библиотеки в проект с исполняемым файлом?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

Имеется проект библиотеки, для данного проекта я создал подпроект для ручного тестирования работы (вообще это просто подпроект с примером работа).

Структура проекта:

[image: структура проекта]

после сборки проекта, библиотеки лежат в папке `cmake-build-debug` а исполняемый фаил примера в `cmake-build-debug/examples/Base`. Как можно в CMake переместить библиотеки в директорию `cmake-build-debug/examples/Base` ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`examples/Base` - является подпроектом.

Основной `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
#### PROJECT TMXL BUILD ####
project(TMXL)
set(TMLX_LIBRARY_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(TMXL_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/TMXL")

file(GLOB TMXL_LIBRARY_HEADERS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/TMXL/*.h")
file(GLOB TMXL_LIBRARY_SOURCES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/TMXL/*.cpp")
add_library(${TMLX_LIBRARY_NAME} SHARED ${TMXL_SOURCE_LIST} ${TMXL_LIBRARY_HEADERS} ${TMXL_LIBRARY_SOURCES})

find_package(SFML REQUIRED window graphics system)
if(SFML_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(${TMLX_LIBRARY_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
endif()

#include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extlibs")
set(TINYXML2_LIBRARY_NAME tinyxml2)
add_library(${TINYXML2_LIBRARY_NAME} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extlibs/tinyxml2/tinyxml2.h"
        "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extlibs/tinyxml2/tinyxml2.cpp")
target_link_libraries(${TMLX_LIBRARY_NAME} tinyxml2)
#### PROJECT TMXL BUILD ####

#### EXAMPLES BUILD ####
add_subdirectory(examples/Base)
install(TARGETS ${TINYXML2_LIBRARY_NAME} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
#### EXAMPLES BUILD ####
```

Подпроект с примером `examples/Base/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(BaseExample)

include_directories(${TMXL_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

install(TARGETS ${TINYXML2_LIBRARY_NAME} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
install(TARGETS ${TMLX_LIBRARY_NAME} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${TMLX_LIBRARY_NAME})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${TINYXML2_LIBRARY_NAME})
```

Comment: Я делал нечто подобное [этой](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13429998/6944845) командой

Comment: @Tocic а можно заставить exe искать библиотеки в папке куда у меня собираются эти библиотеки? чтобы не копировать их в папку с запускаемым файлом?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то вам нужно использовать один из "выходных" путей (LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH, например), полученных при сборке библиотеки, при сборке вашей основной программы (через find_library, например)

Comment: У Вас же есть `install` в скрипте, он не устраивает? Если проблема с путями, то выставляйте переменные в основном файле, где и прописывайте все пути, которые потом будете использовать в `install` и прочих местах, где нужны ожидаемые пути развёртывания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `cmake` поддерживает использование различных [комманд](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/manual/cmake.1.html?highlight=cmakehttps://) (кроссплатформенные), среди которых есть комманды для копирования файлов и директорий: `copy` и `copy_directory`. Использовать их можно с помощью `add_custom_target` примерно вот так:

```
add_custom_target(new_target
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy file ${directory}/file
  )
```

Эта комманда скопирует файл `file` из `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` в `directory` (некая переменная в которой находится путь) в файл с именем `file`. Все предельно просто.

Теперь нужно разобраться с директориями. Все ваши скомпилированные либы и экзешники отпраляются в папки, на которые указывают следующие переменные:

```
CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIR
CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIR
CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIR
```

При этом под `windows`, например, динамические либы будут отправляться в `RUNTIME` так как там нет `rpath`. По умолчанию они равны `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` для каждого проекта. Вообще лучше всего в верхнем `CMakeLists.txt` определить эти переменные для того, чтобы все что будет собрано хранилось централизовано. В таком случае вы должны будете перенести вашу папку в `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIR`. Это будет примерно как:

```
 add_custom_target(copy_target ALL
   ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/folder ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIR}/folder
   DEPENDS my_program
   COMMENT "Copy neded folder to compiling executable"
   )
```

Также и с файлами. Но вообще, если вам нужно скопировать библиотеки, которые вы компилируете - то это будет неверный подход. Вместо этого вам будет достаточно просто определить мной вышеназванные переменные и `cmake` сам сложит все куда надо при чем в зависимости от системы.